# way to prevent lag between conditional render svelte

Tags: video-streaming, lazy-loading, render, svelte, conditional-rendering

In my svelte app, I have a conditional statement that goes something like this. "If the video source exists, render the Video component, else always render a default image". I am finding that when the video is about to load, the default image goes away and there is a blank screen for like 1-3 seconds. Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want this "lag". I only want the image to disappear when the video is actually ready and can instantly show.

ps: the videosrc is being called from graphql schema if that matters

```
        {#if videoSrc}
            <Video src={videoSrc}/>
        {:else}
            <img alt={imageSrc} src={imageSrc} />
        {/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably combine the placeholder with the video component, this would make it easier to combine the states "not having a source at all" and "not having loaded the source yet".

Once you have a source, you can set it on a video element and still visually hide it while listening for events like [`canplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) or [`loadeddata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event), to only show the player then.

Comment: So if I understand you mean to pass the image src down into the "Video" component and conditionally render there? (and rename the Component probably)

Comment: Pass down the image source, yes. Renaming is probably not necessary, a high level video component may very well have a splash screen function.